# update database call a specific migration

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I try to update my database after migration (V2 is the name of the migration) :

```
dnx ef database update V2 -c DataContext -p Infrastructure
```

I have an error because dnx try to execute all migrations et not just V2.

```
Applying migration '20151127095324_V1'
...
There is already an object named 'myEntity' in the database
```

Have u an idea why it try to apply V1 migration ?

Thanks,

Comment: I found the same if  EF7 thinks V1 hasn't been run on the database, it seems to want to run it . Perhaps it thinks this is the case. In your database check for __EFMigrationsHistory table and see if V1 is there before you run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below should work

```
dnx ef database update -c DataContext -p Infrastructure
```

If not, please check if "migration history" table has an entry for migration "v1"